# Replacing HDD with a new - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, hard-disk

I am dual-booting Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 20.04. My Ubuntu partition is 60gb and I ran out of space. I'm trying to replace the disk with a larger one, but I don't want to copy Windows and I'm afraid that I might lose files from Ubuntu. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Install Ubuntu on the new drive, then copy your files over.

Comment: @berndbausch I had the same idea but i wasn't sure how to do this and if it keeps the installed packages and apps.

Comment: Wait, are you *replacing* the disk, or just *adding* a new disk without removing the old one? If you're replacing the disk, you're going to have to copy Windows if you want to keep using it.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield I am replacing the old one (if I have, I will copy Windows)

Comment: If you copy all files, it keeps installed packages. After all, they are also just files. This also copies the entire system configuration. Caution: Any configuration that uses some hardware ID, e.g. MAC addresses, needs to be adjusted.

Comment: @berndbausch do you have any idea how i can do it?

Comment: Install Ubuntu on the new disk. Boot from it. Become root. Mount the old Ubuntu partition. cd to the mount point. Run this command: `find home var etc | cpio -pdumva /`. This leaves files' ownership and timestamps unchanged. It treats symbolic links correctly, but I am not certain about hard links. It only copies /home, /var and /etc, which should be sufficient. I'd keep the old Ubuntu partition around, just in case.

Comment: Another option is cloning the partition to the new disk with a tool like Clonezilla, but I don't know how hard it is to clone it to a larger partition (or to enlarge the cloned partition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is make an image of your old disk onto the new one. You will need a bootable Live CD or USB thumb drive (if your computer can boot from thumb drives), ideally an Ubuntu 20.04. If your Windows partition isn't the first one on the drive (or at least the first one after the boot partition, UEFI partition, etc.), then you're going to need a Windows install disk as well.

1. Make a backup of all important files, as any messing around with the disk like this has the potential to lose data.
2. With the computer off, attach the new disk to the system.
3. Boot from the Live CD.
4. Open a terminal, and type `ls /dev/sd?`, which will list all the hard drives your system recognizes. You should see two, `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. If you see anything else, **STOP** and ask here what you need to do.
5. Now we need to figure out which disk is the old one, and which the new. Type `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`. If it complains about not being able to find an MBR or Partition Table, then this is the new disk. If it doesn't complain, this is the old disk. If this is the old disk, type `p` to get a list of all the partitions on the disk, and take a picture of it with your phone; we may need all those numbers later. In either case, use `q` to quit fdisk.
6. Repeat step #5 with `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`, just to verify that you've got the disk identifiers the right way around. Also, if `/dev/sdb` is the old disk, you'll need to take a picture of the list of partitions.
7. This is the dangerous step, so make **absolutely sure** you've got the right device nodes in the right place. To actually make the image, type `sudo dd if=<old drive> of=<new drive> bs=4M status=progress`.
8. Go get a cup of coffee or something. This is going to take a while.
9. Once `dd` finishes, type `sudo fdisk <new drive>`, then use the `p` command to print the list of partitions and compare it to the picture you took of the old drive's partition list. If all the numbers match, then congratulations, you're done! If not, it means that the new disk uses a different block size than the old one, so you're going to have to completely recreate the partition table. Use the `d` command to delete the partitions one by one (this doesn't delete the data, only the partition information), then use the `n` command to recreate the partitions one by one using the numbers from the photo, then use the `t` command to change each partition's type to match what it was on the old disk. After all that, use the `p` command again to re-verify that the partitions match the photo, and the `w` command to write your changes to disk.
10. Shut the system down, remove the old disk, and set it aside for safe keeping.

At this point, you should be able to boot to your new disk, in both Windows and Linux. Since this is an exact image of your old hard drive, everything will be exactly the same, all your files, settings, installed software, etc. Of course, that also means that your Linux partition is going to be the same size as before, and is still going to be just as full. To actually be able to *use* the extra space you spent so much trouble to get, you're going to need to do some partition editing.

Boot from the Live CD again, and open GParted. This is a pretty easy-to-use program that lets you move and resize partitions. Just select a partition, and click the "Resize/Move" button on the toolbar to move or resize it. There's an "Undo" button if you change your mind about something. Once you've gotten everything the way you want it, click the "Apply" button to actually make the changes (you can't Undo after you click Apply). There are a few gotchas to be aware of, however:

If you have a separate `/boot` partition, you can move and resize your main Linux partition all you want. If you don't, however, moving the start of the Linux partition will (temporarily) make you unable to boot Linux. Fortunately, Ubuntu comes with a program called "boot-repair" that fixes such issues.

1. Boot to your Ubuntu Live CD (if you're not already there).
2. Install boot-repair with the following three commands (internet access required): `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`
3. Run boot-repair by typing `sudo boot-repair`, and follow the instructions it gives you. It will give you a link to more info about your system; if it doesn't work, give us that link.

Windows suffers a similar issue; if you move the start of the Windows partition, it won't boot. To fix it, boot from the Windows CD, get to a command line (the exact details of how to get a command line vary widely between versions, you'll just have to look around until you find it), and type `bootrec /fixmbr`. Note that this may disable access to your Linux system, so once Windows is working, you'll need to follow the above steps to fix the Linux boot as well.

Comment: +1 excellent step-by-step intro, except that in step 9, instead of dancing the high-wire dance and recreating the partition table right off the bat, I would just make the block size of the new volume the same as that of the old.  This can be checked with: `sudo blockdev --getbsz /dev/<vol_name>`. You should get the block size as an integer between 512 bytes and 4096 bytes and format the new volume accordingly UNLESS there is a good reason to change it on the new drive or the new drive is so big that a large block size of 4096 bytes is needed anyway.

Comment: @Games08: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345804/difference-between-blocks-and-sectors  to choose your block size if you are in need of a change. Otherwise just use the same size as the old volume for the new volume. Note that in some `fdisk`  implementations, the man page will talk about "sector" sizes instead of "block" sizes to describe the `-b` option you need to resort to to specify the block size when formatting a volume. It's a terminology abuse.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield All this seems like it will work. I have 2 questions: 1.  When you say live CD do you mean a seperate installation disk (If yes, can I use a bootable USB instead)?      2.  My new HDD hasn't arrived yet. In my 
old disk it has some more space but it's on the Windows partition. Is it safe to resize the Ubuntu's partition with Windows? Thank you!

Comment: @Games08 1. A Live CD lets you run the OS directly from the CD/DVD without installing it on the hard drive, while an install CD is used to install the OS. Ubuntu, like a lot of modern-day LInux distros, put both options on one CD. When you boot from the CD, pick the "Try Ubuntu without installing" option to get into live mode. 2. Windows doesn't know about Linux's EXT file systems, so you'd need third-party software to resize a Linux partition from within Windows. Much easier, IMHO, to use a Linux Live CD.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield Ehmm... it shows a 3rd disk named `/dev/sdc` (and the other two, `/dev/sda` & `/dev/sdb`)

Comment: @Games08 Ah, it only just now occurred to me that, if you're booting from a USB stick, it's going to show up as a third hard drive. Do an `fdisk` on all three. The `p` command should give you the size of each drive, and match the size of each device node to the actual size of the drive it goes to. (And write down your results. This is not something you want to get confused on.)

Comment: @HiddenWindshield It Works! I have some problems with resizing the partitions, but overall it works! Thank you!